# Is there an option in Pycaret to stop looking for best model if the current models achieve a desired performance

Tags: python, classification, pycaret

I have a data frame with 860k rows, and I am using GPU but still very slow. I decided to stop the training, and I am satisfied with the performance of the last model.

Is there an option in Pycaret to stop looking for the best model if the current models achieve the desired performance?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of, but you can open an enhancement request here if not already present: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues